# How to correct the error in plotting the ROCR plot?

Tags: r

> Error in performance(pred, "tpr", "fpr") :    Wrong argument types:
>   First argument must be of type 'prediction'; second and optional third
>   argument must be available performance measures!

```
s <- svm(Column20 ~ ., data =train) 
pred <- predict(s, test[,-20]) 
x <-table( pred, test$Column20) 
P <- performance(x, "tpr", "fpr")
```

if  I change this line of code  as x <-prediction( pred, test$Column20), im getting this error

```
 Error in prediction(pred, test$Column20) : 
  Format of predictions is invalid.
```

I do not understand the error properly.could you please explain what I have done wrong? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should use `x <- prediction( pred, test$Column20)` and then `P <- performance(x, "tpr", "fpr")`

Comment: s <- svm(Column20 ~ .,  data =train)
log.pred <- predict(s, test[,-20])                                                                      x <-table( pred, test$Column20)
P <- performance(x, "tpr", "fpr") , this is my entire code. I dont the error.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple illustrative example. I hope it can help you.

```
library(e1071)
library(ROCR)

df <- iris[,1:4]
df$virgi <- as.numeric(iris$Species=="virginica")
svmMod <- svm(virgi ~ ., data = df)

svmPred <- predict(svmMod, df[,-5]) 

svmPredictiction <- prediction(svmPred, df$virgi)
svmPerf <- performance(svmPredictiction, "tpr", "fpr")

plot(svmPerf)
```

[image]